# Blender Python Script calling DLL

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to run a simulation in Blender (headless) using a Python script which calls a C DLL through ctypes.  I don't understand the threading.

If I run the python module standalone (outside of Blender) it executes the script and the C calls in the correct order.

When I run the script through Blender the C calls are made in a different order. The C calls appear to execute before the Python script in the logs.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: How and when are you making the calls and how are you monitoring/debugging the call order?

Comment: I am using using standard out in the python module and in the C dll. I believe the problem has to do with the global interpreter lock.  I am going to look in the Blender code and see how it does callbacks.

Comment: The confusion was due to the logging buffer in Python resulting in timing differences from standard out/error between the C dll and in python. Always use flush=true in the Python print function if working with C dlls.